# get header text using AssociatedHeaderCellID

Tags: c#, asp.net

How go I get the text values from a header cell in asp.net Table object using using `AssociatedHeaderCellID`?

I've tried:

```
string headerCell = cell.AssociatedHeaderCellID.GetValue(); // bad code  
string headerCell = cell.AssociatedHeaderCellID.ToString(); // returns "System.String[]"
```

I expect the return to be the text of the table header like `"Location"`.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.associatedheadercellid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The AssociatedHeaderCellID property contains a list of header cell
>   programmatic identifiers that provide header information of the
>   TableCell control. The list of header cell identifiers is rendered as
>   a comma delimited list into the HTML  element's header attribute.

So you should write

```
string headerCell = cell.AssociatedHeaderCellID == null ? "" : 
                       string.Join(",", cell.AssociatedHeaderCellID);
```

Comment: This returns a blank. Are you sure this is the right way?

Comment: This is totally by the documentation. Can you view you `TableCell` controls's header in the source?